# React Native: AppState.addEventListener registering duplicate events on resume when tapping a notification

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I have code which I want to run when my app resumes from the background. To this end, I register an event using AppState.addEventListener().

```
  const handleAppStateChange = () => {
    console.log('Do stuff')
  }

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
  }
```

When I normally exit the app and resume, it prints 'do stuff' as expected, however (and here is the issue), when the app is minimised and I tap on a notification, the app will print 'Do stuff' twice.

I have figured out it's because when I tap a notification, it seems to re-run the app (including the constructor part), which means it creates a second event listener...

So, does anyone know either why it's doing that when tapping on a notification and if I can prevent it (using react-native-push-notification plugin), or alternatively if there is a way I can ensure that duplicate events are not registered?

This is happening on my Android physical device, not sure if it's an iOS issue as well, but just thought I would check if anyone knew if this was possible)

Comment: `componentDidMount` is propably better for your event subscription.Maybe thats also your entire problem why it's sometimes get subscribed but not unsubscribed.

Comment: I did test this thank you, but I think the problem is not necessarily related to it (but you can argue it's probably a better place to put it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after much agonising, I have managed to come up with a solution. It's not great, but gets the job done for now.

```
if (AppState._eventHandlers.change.size === 0) {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
}
```

I feel the AppState page https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate, is woefully inadequate, and that is why the only option I could see right now is this private method. Will try and follow up with the team if this could be improved, because it would make sense that in some cases you don't want duplicated events to be registered.

Comment: Now I have this tsc error: error TS2339: Property '_eventHandlers' does not exist on type 'AppStateStatic'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is still the correct one, however it might cause crashes on iOS 13. It works fine on Android.

My suggestion is to explicitly check for Android:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && AppState._eventHandlers.change.size === 0)
```

Comment: What crashes does it cause and why? Happy to update my answer if you can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

When I used

```
if (AppState._eventHandlers.change.size === 0) {
```

AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
}
I got this error :

```
Now I have this tsc error: error TS2339: Property '_eventHandlers' does not exist on type 'AppStateStatic'.
```

So,I rollbacked it and then I resolved AppState.addEventListener registering duplicate events on resume when tapping a notification, by changing arrow function to function in this way:

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', controlSocketConnection);
function controlSocketConnection() { // some code }
```